# Not able to call javascript function

Tags: 2010, javascript, modal-dialog

I am adding an onclick event from code behind file to a hyperlink control. I am trying to call a javascript function `ViewInModal` from this onclick event. I am picking up a value from a grid view and passing it to the javascript function. But the function is not getting triggered.
I am using the following line of code.

```
 hypLink1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "ViewInModal("+ DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ViewSome").ToString()+")");
```

Is there anything wrong in this line? Please help guys

Comment: @AmalHashim I called the function without any parameter before and the function was getting called but after I made my function to accept a parameter it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing as below

```
hypLink1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "ViewInModal('"+ DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ViewSome").ToString()+"')");
```